# Select next 'free' integer based on input

Tags: mysql

I have table which contains some data which (among other columns) has auto increment column "id" and one column called "sifra".

I need to find next free number "sifra" based on some input (numbers).

If I have following values in my table for column "sifra":

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 6
- 11
- 12
- 14
- 322
- 323
- 324
- 678
- 6790
- 6810
- 6812

If I send value "1" mysql should return "10" because it's the next free integer with leading "1" and if i pass "32" it should return "320".

If i pass "681" it should return "6811".

This is what i've tried so far:

```
 SELECT LEFT(MAX(a.sifra), 5) + 1 max_val
 FROM artikli as a
left join artikli as arttab
on a.sifra + 1 = arttab.sifra
WHERE a.sifra LIKE '" & sifra & "%'
```

Comment: Why would 32 not return 32 since 32 is free and why would 681 not return 681?

Comment: Because i'm not trying to find a number with leading "3" and number with leading "68". If you look closely you can see that i'm appending wildcard after sifra (%). Look at those numbers (each one) as groups for items. P.Salmon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following stored procedure:

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists getfreenum $$
create procedure getfreenum(num int)
begin

    set @compare := (num * 10);

    set @maxId := (select sifra from artikli where sifra >=  @compare order by sifra asc limit 1);

    while @compare = @maxId do
        set @compare := @compare + 1;
        set @maxId = (select sifra from artikli where sifra >=  @compare order by sifra asc limit 1);
    end while;

    select @compare;
end $$
delimiter ;
```